# Data presentation in SQLITE table

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table:

[image]

I want it to look like this using SQLITE:

[image]

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION for 2 queries each fetching one of the columns `2349` and `2350`:

```
select
  emp_id,
  2349 obj_id,
  `2349` score
from tablename  
union
select
  emp_id,
  2350 obj_id,
  `2350` score
from tablename  
order by emp_id, obj_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n5suyva1uiod27jxR3zY5E/0)